# .NET MySQL got random "query execution interrupted"

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

I don't know why, using Visual Studio and a standalone MySQL server, i got randomly this error executing queries (most of the time with non-select queries).

I already used `CommandTimeout = 10000;` but the problem persist.

I'm sure that the server is running (it's a random error) and the queries are correct.

My code is simply as :

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(_query, connection);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;

//Execute command
int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <=== Random exception here
```

Comment: doesn't sound like a timeout, sounds like your connection gets jacked or spid is getting killed etc...

Comment: I think the some thing but i don't know what do.

Comment: would start with the actual full stack trace

Comment: Start with catching the exception (and the stack trace).

Comment: The stack trace give me only this:
in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   in MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   in Frameworks.MySQL.ExecuteNonQuery(String _query)

Comment: Now the error is "Fatal error encountered during command execution." i don't know why it changed

EDIT: The inner exception say: +  
{"Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset."}

Comment: What is the query?  Is it an ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: Yes, it's a simple INSERT INTO t_yards SET name = 'test'...

Comment: Why not?  It inserti a record with name = test.